# Using WysiwygFieldWidget in a z3c.form form

Tags: forms, plone, z3c.form

I'm creating a form with z3c.form and for a textarea, I would like to have a wysiwyg interface.

So I use plone.directives.form to handle that.

In my interfaces.py :

```py
from zope import schema
from plone.directives import form
from plone.app.z3cform.wysiwyg import WysiwygFieldWidget

from zope.i18nmessageid import MessageFactory
_ = MessageFactory('BSWMinisite')

class IMinisiteProperties(form.Schema):
    """ """
    form.widget(edito=WysiwygFieldWidget)
    edito = schema.Text(title = u"Edito", 
                    required=False)
```

In my content.py :

```py
from plone.directives import form
from z3c.form import button
from Products.CMFPlone import PloneMessageFactory as plMF
from plone.z3cform.layout import wrap_form
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName

from Products.BSWMinisite.interfaces import IMinisiteProperties


class MinisitePropertiesForm(form.SchemaForm):
    """ """

    schema = IMinisiteProperties
    ignoreContext = True # don't use context to get widget data
    @button.buttonAndHandler(plMF('label_save', default=u'Save'), name='apply')
    def handleApply(self, action):
        """ stuff """

    @button.buttonAndHandler(plMF('label_cancel', default=u'Cancel'),
                         name='cancel')
    def handleCancel( self, action):
        self.request.RESPONSE.redirect( self.context.absolute_url() )

MinisitePropertiesView = wrap_form(MinisitePropertiesForm)
```

And in the configure.zcml I have :

```xml
<include package="plone.directives.form" file="meta.zcml" />
<include package="plone.directives.form" />
<browser:page
  for="*"
  name="minisite_properties"
  class=".browser.content.MinisitePropertiesView"
  permission="cmf.ModifyPortalContent"
  />
```

When I go to @@minisite_properties I see my field, but no wysiwyg.
Do you hnow where I missed something ?

Comment: There has been some problems with WYSIWYG field and Dexterity in past. Which Dexterity and TinyMCE version you are using?

Comment: I'm on Plone 4.1.3
CKeditor 3.6.2
And I don't have dexterity, juste z3c.form and plone.directives.form

Comment: I tried with ckeditor and with TinyMCE, but same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was I didn't have the correct version of dexterity, and my package wasn't grok'ed correctly.

In the buildout, to pin the correct dexterity :

```xml
extends = 
    base.cfg
    versions.cfg
    http://good-py.appspot.com/release/dexterity/1.1?plone=4.1.3
```

In the main configure.zcml :

```xml
<configure xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
       xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser"
       xmlns:five="http://namespaces.zope.org/five"
       xmlns:i18n="http://namespaces.zope.org/i18n"
       xmlns:grok="http://namespaces.zope.org/grok"
       i18n_domain="BSWMinisite">

  <!-- Grok the package to initialise schema interfaces and content classes -->
  <grok:grok package="." />

  <browser:page
    for="*"
    name="minisite_properties"
    class=".browser.content.MinisitePropertiesView"
    permission="cmf.ModifyPortalContent"
    />
  ...
```

And then in my content.py :

```py
from five import grok

class MinisitePropertiesForm(form.SchemaForm):
    """ """

    grok.context(IMinisiteProperties)
    schema = IMinisiteProperties
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is my sample code for Dexterity content schema using Dexterity 1.1 pindowns (see Dexterity manual, installation part)

```py
from five import grok
from zope import schema

from plone.directives import form, dexterity

from plone.app.z3cform.wysiwyg import WysiwygFieldWidget

class ICourseInfoContent(form.Schema):
    """
    Content page for CourseInfo folders
    """

    # Autofilled by course id
    title = schema.TextLine(title=u"Title", required=True, default=u"")

    # -*- Your Zope schema definitions here ... -*-
    form.widget(body=WysiwygFieldWidget)
    body = schema.Text(title=u"Body (top)")
```

Comment: It's not a dexterity content that I want, just a z3c.form do I really need to have dexterity ?

Comment: You are using plone.directives.form, not plain z3c.form which is ZCML and stuff. Dexterity is based on the same plone.directives.form. Also, make sure that your package is properly grok'ed so that class level directives are executed http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/components/grok.html

Comment: Ok, so for convenience I could just install dexterity which includes all of this.
I take a look at the grok part. Thanks

Comment: That was that, I installed dexterity with the correct pined version. And then grok'ed it, and it works.